# Prevent multiple html elements' selection on doubleclick

Tags: html, css

When I doubleclick on the text "five", all the other elements also get selected. For e.g. copy/paste results in "OneTwoThreeFourFive". And they don't even get deselected easily!

How can I avoid this multiple text selection behaviour ?

```css
      .App {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        height: 3em;
        width: 20em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 3em;
        width: 5em;
        background-color: darkseagreen;
        border: 1px solid green;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .one {
        left: 0;
      }
      .two {
        left: 5em;
      }
      .three {
        left: 10em;
      }
      .four {
        left: 15em;
      }
      .five {
        left: 20em;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="App">
      <div class="item one">One</div>
      <div class="item two">Two</div>
      <div class="item three">Three</div>
      <div class="item four">Four</div>
      <div class="item five">Five</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem, and I solved it by putting `display: inline-table` on my (my equivalent of) the `item` elements.

```css
      .App {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        height: 3em;
        width: 20em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 3em;
        width: 5em;
        background-color: darkseagreen;
        border: 1px solid green;
        display: inline-table;
      }
      .one {
        left: 0;
      }
      .two {
        left: 5em;
      }
      .three {
        left: 10em;
      }
      .four {
        left: 15em;
      }
      .five {
        left: 20em;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="App">
      <div class="item one">One</div>
      <div class="item two">Two</div>
      <div class="item three">Three</div>
      <div class="item four">Four</div>
      <div class="item five">Five</div>
    </div>
```

Apparently putting the elements in table mode is enough of a hint to Chrome that the text in the element is separate from the text around it.  There are other hacks that also work, such as:

```
  .item:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }
```

(putting an invisible line break at the start of the item)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue in Chrome when using floats - the float removes the whitespace from between the items so all of the text is running together.

You can remove the float and set `display:flex` on the parent or add whitespace within the child divs. Either way, don't use `pointer-events:none;` on the items because then you are  only able to interact with the parent.

```css
.App {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        height: 3em;
        width: 20em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 3em;
        width: 5em;
        background-color: darkseagreen;
        border: 1px solid green;        
      }
      .one {
        left: 0;
      }
      .two {
        left: 5em;
      }
      .three {
        left: 10em;
      }
      .four {
        left: 15em;
      }
      .five {
        left: 20em;
      }
```

```html
<div class="App">
      <div class="item one">One </div>
      <div class="item two">Two </div>
      <div class="item three">Three </div>
      <div class="item four">Four </div>
      <div class="item five">Five </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/romiul/pen/bzvwXM) link. I change some css code

```
  .item {
    float:left;
    height: 3em;
    width: 5em;
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:block;
  }
```

Comment: Still same issues - When I click on the text "five", all the other elements also get selected. For e.g. copy/paste results in "OneTwoThreeFourFive". And they don't even get deselected easily!

Comment: Sorry, it is when I double-click. I've updated the question.

Comment: please check codepen now. hope it will works. Thanks

Comment: Even if this answer worked, it would need to explain why the solution works in order to be a 'good' answer.